# xamarin.android - support different screen size with dimens files

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-resources

I created dimens files for 320dp, 360dp and 480dp screen sizes in values folder.

[image: Values Folder]

However when I use values from dimens in my project, It would always take values from dimens-sw480dp. I tested it on 320dp and 360dp width screen devices.

I also tried changing files names...dimens-sw480dp.xml to dimens-sw480.xml but nothing changed.

Comment: you do not have to change the dimens.xml file name you just need to change the folder name

Comment: create folders in the resource drawables. Like here https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/alternate-resources-images/alternate-resources-vs.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had to create values directory for every screen resolution.

[image]